# adobe muse php on google app engine php handler

Tags: php, google-app-engine, adobe, handler, muse

I have read every post on here and adobe to try to figure this out.  I am switching my site over to google app engine.  The site was hosted on godaddy just fine.  The problem is with the php handler. The form is in html and and the then submits info to php file.

I have seen so many app.yaml files,but none specify the mime-type for php.  Everytime I change the mime type I get the wrong results.  When I do not include the php handler Launcher does not upload the php files.  If I dont choose a mime type Launcher defaults to application/octet then the files just downloads when I enter its url. When I use text/html I get nothing. I have tried - url : /(.*)
  script: (\1).php to no avail.  application/x-php download, text/x-php server error.

```
application: optical-realm-757
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

default_expiration: "30d"

handlers:

- url: /(.*\.php)
  mime_type: text/x-php
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.php)
  expiration: "1h"

- url: /(.*\.(appcache|manifest))
  mime_type: text/cache-manifest
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(appcache|manifest))
  expiration: "0m"

- url: /(.*\.atom)
  mime_type: application/atom+xml
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.atom)
  expiration: "1h"

- url: /(.*\.crx)
  mime_type: application/x-chrome-extension
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.crx)

- url: /(.*\.css)
  mime_type: text/css
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.css)

- url: /(.*\.eot)
  mime_type: application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.eot)

- url: /(.*\.htc)
  mime_type: text/x-component
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.htc)

- url: /(.*\.html)
  mime_type: text/html
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.html)
  expiration: "1h"

- url: /(.*\.ico)
  mime_type: image/x-icon
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.ico)
  expiration: "7d"

- url: /(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.js)

- url: /(.*\.json)
  mime_type: application/json
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.json)
  expiration: "1h"

- url: /(.*\.m4v)
  mime_type: video/m4v
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.m4v)

- url: /(.*\.mp4)
  mime_type: video/mp4
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.mp4)

- url: /(.*\.(ogg|oga))
  mime_type: audio/ogg
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(ogg|oga))

- url: /(.*\.ogv)
  mime_type: video/ogg
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.ogv)

- url: /(.*\.otf)
  mime_type: font/opentype
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.otf)

- url: /(.*\.rss)
  mime_type: application/rss+xml
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.rss)
  expiration: "1h"

- url: /(.*\.safariextz)
  mime_type: application/octet-stream
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.safariextz)

- url: /(.*\.(svg|svgz))
  mime_type: images/svg+xml
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(svg|svgz))

- url: /(.*\.swf)
  mime_type: application/x-shockwave-flash
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.swf)

- url: /(.*\.ttf)
  mime_type: font/truetype
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.ttf)

- url: /(.*\.txt)
  mime_type: text/plain
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.txt)

- url: /(.*\.unity3d)
  mime_type: application/vnd.unity
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.unity3d)

- url: /(.*\.webm)
  mime_type: video/webm
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.webm)

- url: /(.*\.webp)
  mime_type: image/webp
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.webp)

- url: /(.*\.woff)
  mime_type: application/x-font-woff
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.woff)

- url: /(.*\.xml)
  mime_type: application/xml
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.xml)
  expiration: "1h"

- url: /(.*\.xpi)
  mime_type: application/x-xpinstall
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.xpi)

# image files
- url: /(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))

# audio files
- url: /(.*\.(mid|midi|mp3|wav))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(mid|midi|mp3|wav))  

# windows files
- url: /(.*\.(doc|exe|ppt|rtf|xls))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(doc|exe|ppt|rtf|xls))

# compressed files
- url: /(.*\.(bz2|gz|rar|tar|tgz|zip))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(bz2|gz|rar|tar|tgz|zip))

# index files
- url: /(.+)/?
  static_files: static/\1/index.html
  upload: static/(.+)/index.html
  expiration: "15m"

- url: /(.+)
  static_files: static/\1/index.html
  upload: static/(.+)/index.html
  expiration: "15m"

# site root
- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html
  expiration: "15m"
```

Comment: please post your entire app.yaml file

Comment: @StuartLangley sorry about that thanks.

Comment: how is that your app.yaml? it's not in yaml format.

Comment: @StuartLangley i downloaded it from a suggestion here:https://gist.github.com/darktable/873098

Comment: Better you read this and do it properly. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig

Comment: I've submitted an edit to clear up the app.yaml confusion. Also, you can't just put any old PHP on GAE - it has to be coded to the GAE APIs. I am no Muse expert, but are you sure it can produce PHP usable on GAE? The app.yaml you have provided will only serve static files, it won't actually run PHP. Stuart's link will get you started on that. However at a wild guess I think where you might be going wrong is that you are trying to upload the Muse files to a GAE static dir and expecting them to run? in a nutshell, that  will never happen :-)